# What forms of ID do I need to fly domestically from Arkansas after January, 2018?

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, tsa, real-id

My wife has an Arkansas driver's License, though it's not one of the new REAL ID licenses.

The [DHS](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id-public-faqs) says:

> Starting January 22, 2018, passengers who have driver's licenses issued by a state that is **not yet compliant with REAL ID** and that has not received an extension will need to show an alternative form of acceptable identification for domestic air travel. Please see TSA's website for a list of acceptable forms of identification. Passengers who have licenses issued by a state that is compliant or that has an extension to become compliant with REAL ID requirements may continue to use their licenses as usual. For a list of states already in compliance or with an extension visit DHS's REAL ID webpage. DHS continually updates this list as more states come into compliance or obtain extensions.

The [TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) says:

> Adult passengers 18 and over must show valid identification at the airport checkpoint in order to travel.
>
> - Driver's licenses or other state photo identity cards issued by Department of Motor Vehicles (or equivalent)
>
> ...

(and then links back to the DHS site).

Which one of these do I believe? The TSA doesn't list anything else besides a passport - she doesn't currently have one, so does that mean that we need to either get an updated REAL ID driver's license, or a passport? Or is a current Arkansas driver's license valid for travel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the DHS page you linked, under "What do I need to do if...?":

> Fifty-five out of fifty-six states and territories are currently compliant with REAL ID or non-compliant with an extension.  The residents from these states and territories may continue using their driver’s licenses or identification cards, **regardless of whether the license/ID is REAL ID compliant or not**, for accessing Federal facilities (including military bases), entering nuclear power plants, and boarding commercial aircraft.  The February 5, 2018, enforcement date only applies currently to the residents of American Samoa.
>
> Starting October 1, 2020, every state and territory resident will need to present a REAL ID compliant license/ID, or another acceptable form of identification, for accessing Federal facilities, entering nuclear power plants, and boarding commercial aircraft.  This is what we call “card-based” enforcement.  The card, itself, must be REAL ID compliant unless the resident is using an alternative acceptable document such as a passport.

As shown on [this map](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id), Arkansas is compliant, so *all* Arkansas licenses, *including pre-REAL ID ones*, will be accepted until October 1, 2020.  You won't need an updated license until then.

See also my answer to [Do Californians need a REAL ID by October 2018 or 2020?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116828/do-californians-need-a-real-id-by-october-2018-or-2020) for further details about the relevant regulations.

Comment: Or boarding an airplane... apparently someone at DHS needs to fix that ;)

Comment: *"The card, itself, must be REAL ID compliant unless the resident is using an alternative acceptable document such as a passport."* This is a bizarre statement on their part because if you're using a passport then you don't even need an additional ID, right? It's already REAL ID-compliant...

Comment: Yes, it's oddly worded.  Though I wouldn't say that a passport is "REAL ID-compliant" because the REAL ID law doesn't regulate passports at all; it only sets standards for when the federal government may accept state-issued IDs.  But yes, a passport is acceptable ID all by itself.