# Do I need any sort of identification for my child when traveling domestically?

Tags: usa, airlines, minors, domestic-travel

I am planning to travel domestically in the US next month with my daughter who is 5.

In regards to my own identification, I was reviewing [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/112181/135692) to confirm that my driver's license would be sufficient ID for myself. And it seems that per the [TSA's web site](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), I'll be fine with that through 2025.

The TSA's web site indicates that they don't require any identification for children under 18 who are flying, but that I should contact the airline to confirm if they have any requirements. We are traveling with Southwest and reviewing [their information for children flying](https://www.southwest.com/help/flying-with-children), I could not locate anything specific to ID requirements, if any, the airline has for children.

I'm assuming no ID will be required for my daughter based on this lack of information, but is there something I might be missing?

Comment: "to confirm that my driver's license would be sufficient ID for myself. And it seems that per the TSA's web site, I'll be fine with that through 2025." That's only if it's a non-REAL-ID, non-enhanced driver's license. If you have a REAL ID driver's license or enhanced driver's license, you can use that for TSA security checkpoints even after 2025.

Answer (score 2):

This is personal experience only.

My partner and I have flown domestically and internationally, separately and together, with our two children. They first flew at 6 months. International flights required passports, of course, but the most I've carried for domestic flights is their birth certificates but haven't had to produce them. I've taken their birth certificates because they have hyphenated last names so their last name doesn't exactly match mine.